# How do I derive from two base constructors in a way that allows me to have default argument values?

Tags: c#, inheritance, exception, constructor

I'm writing an exception that inherits from ArgumentOutOfRangeException and I want to write constructors that derive from the two base overloads base(string paramName) and base(string paramName, string message) but I want to provide default values for paramName in both constructors and a default value for message in the second. What is the best way to do this? (If it helps, the default value for paramName will be the same in both).

I've thought of overriding the constructor with a single constructor with a third boolean parameter to determine which constructor to call and calling that constructor, but after some testing found out that fails on so many levels.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class TrainingSetCardinalityMismatch : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
{
    public TrainingSetCardinalityMismatch(string paramName = "trainingSets") : base(paramName)
    {
        //code here
    }
    public TrainingSetCardinalityMismatch(string paramName = "trainingSets", message = "Number of training sets provided must match number of answers provided") : base(paramName, message)
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you expect the consumer to use this exception? That is, what combinations of arguments? Does `paramName` really ever need to be defaulted? Even if it doesn't work, some code would give a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: But my gut tells me that you need one exception type that takes `paramName` where there's a parameter being validated, and another exception type that doesn't and passes a default to the base class where there's *not* a parameter being validated.

Comment: General quality tip: a code example wouldn't go amiss here. I sort of get what you mean but an example what you want to do/are currently trying makes it easier to provide a counterexample with key differences.

Comment: @Flater I've added some example code - I'm kind of dabbling in neural networks, and the exception is to be used when updating training sets/answers but the number of sets and answers do not match - that's just one example.

Comment: Based on the updated question, see my comment on sedders123's answer. Again, what are all the ways in which you expect the consumer to use it?

Comment: You need to ask yourself the question which base constructor you want to call if use call `new  TrainingSetCardinalityMismatch()` and if user call ` TrainingSetCardinalityMismatch("something else")`. I would say that **the most probable answer is that you want to keep only the second constructor** in your case.

Comment: @Phil1970 Yeah, that's the conclusion I seem to be reaching as well

Answer (score 2):

You could call the other constructor with your default values like so

```cs
public CustomException(string paramName = "defaultName") : this(paramName, null)
{
}

public CustomException(string paramName = "defaultName", string message = "defaultMessage") : base(paramName, message)
{
}
```

Comment: If you do `new CustomException()`, you get *The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'CustomException.CustomException(string)' and 'CustomException.CustomException(string, string)*. That's not a very good experience for the consumer.

Comment: That's a really good point, I can't think of a way immediately to solve this while still adhering to the constraints of the question. Please do suggest an edit if there something I'm missing :)

Comment: We're still in the exploratory stage here.

Comment: @madreflection Thank you sedders, I was thinking of the case that madreflection brought up myself, and yeah - I think technically it picks the constructor with the least amount of assumptions (the first one), which really I would prefer it to default to the other one, but in either case, it's still ambiguous :/ To answer your question above though, the only time the exception is going to be used is when the user of the class tries to update the training sets and/or answers for the neural network.

Comment: @TaraStahler It doesn't pick up either. The error message I quoted was from an actual test.

Comment: I may just drop the call to the first constructor - this is my first time playing around with exceptions, and tbh I'm not even really sure what the difference is between the two, like if you call the constructor for the ArgumentOutOfRangeException, I'm assuming it still has a message field and it's assigned a default value of it's own? Maybe it's a good idea just to always have that default value overridden with my own default value.

Comment: @TaraStahler That's correct. If you omit the `message` argument, it uses a message taken from string resources. See the private `RangeMessage` property [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/argumentoutofrangeexception.cs). Try it and see if that message is useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well from the question, I can see 2 possibilities.

- You always want the message (second argument)
- You sometime want the message, sometime not and sometime a different message.

In the first case, you would simply remove the definition of the first constructor. You will always have the message if you don't specify the second argument.

```
public class TrainingSetCardinalityMismatch : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
{
    public TrainingSetCardinalityMismatch(
            string paramName = "trainingSets", 
            message = "Number of training sets provided must match number of answers provided") 
        : base(paramName, message)
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

Then you could call it that ways:

```
// default param name + default message
throw new TrainingSetCardinalityMismatch(); 

// custom param, default message
throw new TrainingSetCardinalityMismatch("custom param"); 

// custom param, custom message
throw new TrainingSetCardinalityMismatch("custom param", "custom message");
```

However, it won't allows default param but with custom message.

If you want that, you have a few possibilities:

- One would be to have a constant for the default message and specify it explicitly instead of the hard coded string.
- Another might be to change parameter order if message need to be customized most of the time.
- Another one would be to have a static functions that raise the exception.
- Another one could be to set the default to null if when null is specified remplace by default value. That way, you can use an empty string if you really want no message.
- Another one is to have 2 exception classes (say TrainingSetCardinalityMismatchA`and`TrainingSetCardinalityMismatchB`) and each one has a single constructor.
- Another want would be to use an `enum` instead of a string when using predefined messages and then constructor with custom message would not have any default as it would be used only for specific message.

Usually, I prefer the last way and then I could use resource and a bit of code to load the appropriate string from the `enum` identifier which is relatively easy in C# as you can to `enum_var.ToString()` to get a name and use that name to load a resource by its name using the resource manager (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: For the 4th variation, use a named parameter: `throw new TrainingSetCardinalityMismatch(message: "custom message");` and `paramName` will be defaulted.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create your own constructors and call the base ones like i've shown below

```
class MyArgumentOutOfRangeException : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
{
    public MyArgumentOutOfRangeException(string myName):base("PlaceDefaultNamepropValue")
    {
        // do something with passed my name
    }
    public MyArgumentOutOfRangeException(string myname, string mymessage):base("PlaceDefaultNamepropValue", "PlaceDefaultMessagepropValue")
    {
        // do something with passed my name
        // do something with passed my message
    }
}


class MyOtherArgumentOutOfRangeException : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
{
    public MyOtherArgumentOutOfRangeException(string myName) : this("PlaceDefaultNamepropValue",string.Empty)
    {
        // do something with passed my name
    }
    public MyOtherArgumentOutOfRangeException(string myname, string mymessage) : base("PlaceDefaultNamepropValue", "PlaceDefaultMessagepropValue")
    {
        // do something with passed my name
        // do something with passed my message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than needing to define the type of `message` (use `string message = "..."`), your posted code seems to be functional and doing what you want. So I assume the core of your question is:

> What is the best way to do this? .... I've thought of overriding the constructor with a single constructor with a third boolean parameter to determine which constructor to call and calling that constructor.

As a general rule, I advocate against "choose your own adventure" booleans. While they work on a technical level, there are better alternatives here.

1. Parameters with default values are, by definition, optional parameters. This means you're already able to decide your consumer's constructor selection based on whether the consumer passed the a non-default `message` value. If they didn't, then they're clearly choosing to use the first option. If they did, then they're clearly choosing the second option. They don't need to then also specify a boolean.
2. Does it really matter whether you don't initialize message, or instead explicitly pass `null` or `String.empty` when the consumer doesn't provide a message value? Because if not, then there's no reason to even try and distinguish between the two base constructors.
3. Method overloading inherently exists to give users a way to differentiate between different sets of input parameters, and each overloaded body has its own method (which you can choose to chain or not) so you have total control over what happens in which case. Your boolean would be a (IMO poor) substitute for a cleaner method overload.
4. CYOA booleans tend to only seem viable when you are the consumer of your own code because "I know how I designed this to work". That's often something which leads to avoiding good practice and clean coding. While it will work on a technical level, it's not a good/clean solution and it eventually teaches you bad habits. In most cases, when I use someone else's library, I expect to use the method names to decide what I want to do, not a set of boolean parameters. There are of course exception to this, but they are few and far between. When I've picked the method to use, the parameters should be easy to understand and supply, rather than forcing the user to decide separate behaviors.
5. Encapsulation suggests that your implementation needs to hide complexities from the consumer of your class, where possible. Which means that you're allowed to use a branching structure inside your class, but you shouldn't require the consumer to knowingly make this choice - your class exists to do this for the consumer and simplify the consumer's workload. If you pass the buck to your consumer, then what is your class' value? What does it do for you/the end user? (Note: Don't misinterpret this as an anti-IOC argument. IOC is a good thing, it just isn't really done via booleans. Using IOC, you'd be injecting behavior objects instead of boolean values).

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying, but the exception classes I'm creating are nested and are only intended to be thrown from within the class in which they are defined. The only reason they are public is so that they can be thrown from inside the class to outside the class/

Comment: @TaraStahler: That arguably cuts out 4 and 5 but the other points still apply. Definitely when you're also accounting for other developers working with your code. You asked for the "best way", which should encompass clean and readable code for future (or current) maintainers.